# Merge rows in the same id into array

Tags: php, mysql

I have sentence table :

```
======================================================================
|  id_row  |  id_document |   id_sentence   |       sentence         | 
======================================================================
|     1    |       1      |       0         | Example sentences A    |
|     2    |       1      |       1         | Example sentences B    |
|     3    |       2      |       0         | Example sentences C    |
|     4    |       2      |       1         | Example sentences D    |
======================================================================
```

I wanna merge sentence that have same id_document into array like => `Array( [1] => Array ( [0] => Example sentences A [1] => Example sentences B ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Example sentences C [1] => Example sentences D ))`

Here's the code :

```
<?php
require_once 'conf.php';
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT sentence FROM sentence group by id_document') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $sentence[] = $row['sentence'];
}
print_r($sentence);
?>
```

but, I just get one sentence in every different id_document. Help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index the array on `id_document`, and add new entries to the array like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $sentence[ $row['id_document'] ][] = $row['sentence'];
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, and The result that I get is `Array ( [] => Array ( [0] => Example sentence A [1] => Example sentence C ) )` `Example sentence B` and `Example sentence D` are not printed.

Comment: I don't think you copied it correctly - Make sure you add the additional `[]` before the equals sign.

Comment: I've copied it correctly. I think there's something wrong in my query `$sql = ... `. I've modified my code through my answer below. cmiiw. thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $sentence[$row['id_document']][] = $row['sentence'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  $sentence[$row['id_document']][] = $row['sentence'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code :

```
<?php

require_once 'conf.php';
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT sentence, id_document FROM sentence ') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $sentence[$row['id_document']][] = $row['sentence'];
}
print_r($sentence);

?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what others said to you. You should accept others answer, not your copy-paste.